# Symfony2 upload file with stof uploadable extension

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, stofdoctrineextensions

i'm trying to set up a form with file upload under Symfony2 with the uploadable extension (stof/doctrine)

here are my entities

club

```
<?php  
...  
class Club  
{  
...
/**  
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="my\TestBundle\Entity\File", cascade={"persist"})  
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)  
 */  
private $logo;  
...  
}
```

file

```
<?php  
...  
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM; 
...  
/**
 * File
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="my\TestBundle\Entity\FileRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 * @Gedmo\Uploadable(pathMethod="getPath", callback="myCallbackMethod", filenameGenerator="SHA1", allowOverwrite=true, appendNumber=true)
 */
class File  
{  
 ...

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @Gedmo\UploadableFileName
 */
private $name;

...
```

my form type
clubType

```
$builder->add('logo', new FileType())
```

fileType

```
$builder->add('name', 'file', array(
            'required' => false,
        ))
```

my controller

```
$form = $this->createForm('my_testbundle_club', $club);
$request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->submit($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($club);
            $em->flush();
        }
    }
```

but when i submit my form without uploading anything (upload is not mandatory), i've an error saying that column name in table File cannot be null

but i want that the upload is optional, but if there is an upload, name is mandatory

How can i achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I dont know about that extension, but have you tried adding `nullable=true`  ?   Another option is to add a default value when it is empty, which is probably useful anyway (like a dummy 'logo' image).

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, before flushing, you have to add :

```
if ($club->getLogo()->getPath() instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile) {
    $uploadManager = $this->get('stof_doctrine_extensions.uploadable.manager');
    $uploadManager->markEntityToUpload($club->getLogo(), $club->getLogo()->getPath());
}
```

When uploading a new file, getPath return an instance of uploaded file, if not, it's a string for already saved file or null

see https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.rst#using-uploadable-extension